# É possível detectar compartilhamento no Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

É possivel obter a informação de que o usuário do meu site compartilhou ou não um determinado post da minha página no Facebook?

Existe algum *callback* na API que é executada quando o usuario do meu site clica no botão compartilhar, de modo que eu possa gravar no BD que ele já compartilhou?

Comment: Facebook API? Ajax+PHP?

Comment: wlader, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Editei sua pergunta para tentar torná-la mais clara. Se achar que não está de acordo com sua intenção original, fique à vontade para editá-la. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo utilizar o método de core [FB.ui()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui?locale=pt_BR) do SDK Javascript, do próprio Facebook.

Com ela você poderá utilizar o [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog?locale=pt_BR) e fazer esse controle do post no callback da função.